# How to make a random list using IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm trying to do a flocking simulation in order to better teach myself haskell. I'm running into trouble when trying to generate the initial state for the simulation which requires randomness. I'm trying to generate a list of Boids which all have random initial positions and directions.

In the main function I call this using

```
let numBoids = 10
rBoids <- randomBoids numBoids
```

And `rBoids` I indend to store in an IORef which I can then update every frame, which I think is the right way to do things?

And here is the code which fails:

```
-- Type for the flocking algorithm
data Boid = Boid {
    boidPosition  :: Vector2(GLfloat)
  , boidDirection :: Vector2(GLfloat)
  } deriving Show

randomBoids :: Int -> IO ([Boid])
randomBoids 0 = do
  return []
randomBoids n = do
  b <- randomBoid 
  bs <- (randomBoids (n-1))
  return b : bs

randomBoid = do
  pos <- randomVector
  vel <- randomVector
  return (Boid pos vel)

randomVector = do
  x <- randomRIO(-1.0, 1.0)
  y <- randomRIO(-1.0, 1.0)
  return (Vector2 x y)
```

What actually fails is `return b : bs`. If I change this into `return [b]` it compiles. The error given is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO [Boid]' with actual type `[a0]'
In the expression: return b : bs
In the expression:
  do { b <- randomBoid;
       bs <- (randomBoids (n - 1));
         return b : bs }
In an equation for `randomBoids':
    randomBoids n
      = do { b <- randomBoid;
             bs <- (randomBoids (n - 1));
               return b : bs }
```

I'm pretty lost here, and my understanding of the whole imperative-code-in-a-functional language (and monads) is shaky to say the least. Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: "return (b:bs)" instead of "return b : bs"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because `return b : bs` will make the compiler interpret it as `(return b): bs` To fix this, you can change the statement to `return (b:bs)`. That will make the statement return an `IO[Boid]`

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly having spent at least an hour trying all sort of weird stuff to make this work. Me and Haskell are becoming friends, but mr Haskell seems to be fighting me every inch of the way. Me thinking return was something special, of course it is another function and the same precedence rules apply...

Comment: You are most welcome. Check this page on LYAH - http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output. The section on return, explains why return is different in Haskell.

Comment: Can you please post your code snippet on hpaste and link here. I am getting compilation errors for missing instance declaration for Random GFloat (for randomRIO(-1.0,1.0). GHC version 7.0.4

Comment: Oh, and if you see any stupid mistakes in my code, feel free to tell me! I'm still learning and any help is appreciated. The code is also on github now at https://github.com/Dervall/HetaBalls

Answer (score 8):

Gangadahr is correct.  I only wanted to mention that you can shorten your code a LOT:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

randomBoids n = replicateM n randomBoid

randomBoid = Boid <$> randomVector <*> randomVector

randomVector = Vector2 <$> randomRIO (-1, 1) <*> randomRIO (-1, 1)
```

The first function takes advantage of `replicateM`, which is a very useful function when you want to repeat a monadic action and collect the results.  The latter two functions use `Applicative` style, which is enormously useful.

Comment: I believe `replicateA` would work just as well as `replicateM`, making it entirely applicative.

Comment: @DanBurton `replicateA` is a function in Data.Sequence and returns a functor parameterized over a `Seq`.

Comment: @is7s and @DanBurton, Dan is correct in principle and you can define one that works.  This definition works just fine: `replicateA n m = case n of 0 -> pure []; n' -> (:) <$> m <*> replicateA (n - 1) m`

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez yes that's precisely what I was thinking, thanks for spelling it out. Note that the Data.Sequence implementation behaves a bit differently, constructing the Seq with log(n) invocations of `pure` and `<*>`, while this formulation is more what you would expect: using n invocations of `<*>` and 1 of `pure`. The action is, of course, invoked `n` times in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

The typechecker is reading `return x : xs` as `(return x) : xs`.  If you write `return (x:xs)` it will typecheck.